# One to many relationship in separate database microservices

Tags: database, database-design, microservices

In a microservice architechture with each microserice having it's own database, what is the recommended way of creating a one-to-many relationship between two microservices?

In my case I have two tables:

**products**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product.products (
  "id" UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  ...
)
```

**collections**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS collection.collections (
  "id" UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  ...
)
```

What is recomennded between the following options?

- a) `products` has field `"collection" UUID`
- b) `collections` has field `"products" UUID[]`
- c) both

Or is there another answer which better suits my use case, and if so, why?

Comment: The two Microservices should not be dealing with their DB schema at all.  Instead, the API should drive the interaction.  Basically an id can be stored in one microservice which is then passed along with API to fetch.  

Why can't the two be in same microservice?  They seem to have common domain.

Comment: Actually the collections micro services has `collection.products`, `collection.customers`, etc. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Again, I would question why collections is its own microservice without putting it's functionality into the products/customers/etc. microservices (and the idea of "collection" might also make sense in those as a different name, e.g. "customer groups", "product categories", which is what abstracting it into "collection" obscures).

Comment: @Sid I'm just reading your comment again about "the API should drive the interation". I don't fully understand this. I still need to store the list of product ID's that belong to a given collection somewhere. I'm just not sure how to decide which domain/microservice should have "ownership". I guess the collection in this case. And for the sake of argument, lets pretend the products and collections microservices must be separate in my situation.